# Formatting 2 decimal places in java

Tags: java, decimal

here's my example:

```
double num = 0;

num = 4/3;


System.out.println(num);
```

And my output is 1.0 instead of 1.3

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do int division since this always will result in a truncated int. Instead have your division use at least one double value.

```
double num = 4.0/3.0;
```

Then when you want to display it as a String, format the output so you can choose your decimal places:

```
// one way to do it
// %.3f is for a floating number with 3 digits to the right of the decimal
// %n is for new line
System.out.printf("%.3f%n", num); 

Another:
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(num));
```

Comment: Well you only need to have one be a double (like 4.0/3 or 4/3.0), but both can't hurt :) +1

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, or 4d/3 :P

Comment: I had tried DecimalFormat and BigDecimal too and didn't work :/ They never tough me this in college >:( I'm way better at C++, still kinda new to java and they told me "it's the same thing so... don't worry :D" BS! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
num=(double)4/3;
```

It will return `1.3333`....
Then you can round off the decimals

Answer (score 0):

You should also use String.format(%1.2f, yourDouble) to format your decimal places

Comment: Yes, this code will print the double data, but check that `int/int = int`, so `4/3` will be `1`, you should use `4.0/3.0` in order to get `1.333...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
double value= 255.956666;

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println("value="+bd);
```